# How to add theme in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: color-scheme, visual-studio-code

I recently downloaded the [VS code editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/) which is really nice.
but the only problem I find in it is the color theme, I am use to 
monokai color theme like in sublime text and I can't find a way to edit
the color theme or download a color theme there are only 2 options:

1. Dark Theme
2. Light Theme

How can I add my own theme or duplicate existing one so I will be able to 
edit the color scheme as I want to?

---

I manage to change some of the colors in the following file but still 
I don`t know how to add completely new theme:

```
resources/app/client/vs/monaco/ui/workbench/native/native.main.css
```

---

Looks like color themes will be available soon and it will be a part of a plugin system

[visual-studio-code/suggestions/7756227-theme](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7756227-theme)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

**Visual Studio Code 0.9.0 and later**

There's an [official documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/0.9.0/release-notes/latest.md) on how to add a custom theme.

You need a `.tmtheme` file for the theme you want to add. You can find existing files e.g. on GitHub, [ColorSublime](https://colorsublime.github.io/) or you can define your own theme file (for example with [tmTheme-Editor](https://github.com/aziz/tmTheme-Editor)).

After finding a `.tmtheme` file you have two ways to create an extension based on it.

1. Using a Yeoman generator:

   - Install node.js (if you haven't already done)
   - Install yo (if you haven't already done) by executing `npm install -g yo`
   - Install the Yo generator for code: `npm install -g generator-code`
   - Run `yo code` and select `New Color Theme`
   - Follow the instructions (define the `.tmTheme` file, theme name, ui theme etc.)
   - The generator creates a directory for your extension with the name of the theme in your current working directory.
2. Create the directory on your own:

   - Create a directory with the name of your plugin (only lowercase letters). Let's say we call it `mytheme`.
   - Add a subfolder `themes` and place the `.tmTheme` file inside of it
   - Create a file `package.json` inside the root of the extension folder with content like this

   ```js
   {        
       "name": "theme-mytheme",
       "version": "0.0.1",
       "engines": {
           "vscode": ">=0.9.0-pre.1"
       },
       "publisher": "me",
       "contributes": {
           "themes": [
               {
                   "label": "My Theme",
                   "uiTheme": "vs-dark", // use "vs" to select the light UI theme
                   "path": "./themes/mytheme.tmTheme"
               }
           ]
       }
   }
   ```

**Finally add your extension to Visual Studio Code**

Copy the extension folder to the extension directory. This is:

- on **Windows** `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions`
- on **Mac/Linux** `$HOME/.vscode/extensions`

Restart VSCode and select the new theme in `File -> Preferences -> Color Theme`

**Visual Studio Code 0.8.0**

It's possible to add new themes in Visual Studio Code 0.8.0 (released for insiders on 2015-08-31 [become an insider](https://www.instant.ly/s/Y5nt1/nav#p/186a0)).

After installing VSCode 0.8.0 or higher do this to apply your own theme:

1. Download a `.tmTheme` file or create your own (for example with [tmTheme-Editor](https://github.com/aziz/tmTheme-Editor))
2. Copy the `.tmTheme` file to `%CODEFOLDER%/resources/app/plugins/vs.theme.starterkit/themes`
3. Register the `.tmTheme` file in `%CODEFOLDER%/resources/app/plugins/vs.theme.starterkit/ticino.plugin.json` by adding an entry for it like this:

   ```js
   {
       "id": "vs-theme-mynewtheme", // internal ID
       "label": "MyNewTheme",       // displayed name for the theme
       "uiTheme": "vs-dark",        // general UI appeareance (
                                    // "vs" for light themes, 
                                    // "vs-dark" for dark themes)
       "path": "./themes/myNewTheme.tmTheme" // file path 
   },
   ```
4. Restart VSCode and select the new theme in `File -> Preferences -> Color Theme`

Comment: Somehow this does not work for me, since the monokai theme im using ( which i changed the function keyword color) are the same as the previous theme.. :s weird, cannot apply the theme.

Comment: Did you add a new theme or did you change an existing one? Has the new theme a different name?

Comment: i used the monokai from the builder you suggest tmTheme-Editor then copied the file to the same folder.. But the theme looks the same. And  the name are different only in the end ( monokai vs monkai2) But even edditing the theme file and changing the RGB HEx Values did nothing.. strange.

Comment: I tested it again with the current stable 0.8 release and it works. 
Do you still get the same results when you change the color for "keyword" in the theme editor? 
The color of a token depends on the language definition in VSCode. It's possible that there is no use of the class "function name" in the VSCode syntax highlighter for your language and all function names are  e.g. treated as "Variable". In that case changing the "function name" color takes no effect in VSCode.

Comment: I got to say, they did come up with a truly over complicated way of just defining colors, wtf lol.

Comment: `[Updated link for 2015 VSCode 0.9.1 Release Notes]` https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/main/release-notes/v0_9_0.md

Comment: `[Docs: Creating Your Own Color Theme]` https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_creating-your-own-color-theme

Comment: I verified and confirm that `Copy the extension folder to the extension directory` plus Restarting works. You can verify by copying an existing theme folder such as red and renaming every instance of red in all files.

Answer (score 12):

Adding a completely new theme is not currently supported. 
You can submit your feature requests here, I already heard people asking for this https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 6):

I found that the file - resources/app/client/vs/monaco/ui/workbench/native/native.main.css - is also the right place for changing how fonts are renderer. I was trying to figure out how to disable font smoothing on OS X and found that you can do it here by adding this CSS rule in the file -

```
.monaco-editor {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: none;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to **Wosi**'s answer, for the theme to be recognized and show up in VSC, make sure:

- package.json has no comments (.nls.json, and theme.json, can have them)
- package.json's `name` matches parent folder's name
- theme.json's `name` matches `id`