# Customizing syntax highlighting in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm currently trying to write an extension for a new file type (ANTLR) and wonder how to change the colors used for syntax highlighting in Visual Studio Code. To me it looks as if that is not defined in the extension, but somewhere else. There is no preferences entry for colors nor did I find a CSS file which defines that (which I'd expect since vscode is using Electron). I also looked through the settings file vscode generated and files that came with it, but no clue either. Neither did a web search help. So, I'm kinda lost now.

Can someone give me some hints or point me to the relevant docs?

Comment: The related question `How can I have an extension colorize the syntax the extension is defining without it actually being a color theme the user has to enable?` is asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46377151/how-to-customize-the-color-of-custom-syntax-tokens-in-vscode-extension

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are two concepts at play here:

- language grammars, which turn a text file into tokens with different **scopes**, and
- themes, which colorize those **scopes** in a (hopefully) eye-pleasing way.

If you're writing your own grammar, or converting from TextMate etc., there's a chance you're using different scopes than the ones defined by the theme. In that case, there won't be a clear distinction between the tokens you define, even if they are actually defined.

There are two ways out of this. First one is, extend a theme with your custom scopes and colour them however you want. Not really a good way to go, unless everyone using your language also likes your colour scheme. The other is, use the (limited set of) scopes already defined and colorized by VSCode and the theme authors. Chances are, your language is going to look good in your theme of choice, and good enough in others.

To give you an example, here's the `comment` scope as defined by the default dark VSCode theme.

```js
"name": "Dark Visual Studio",
"settings": [
    {
        "scope": "comment",
        "settings": {
            "foreground": "#608b4e"
        }
    },
```

and here's the equivalent language snippet from the C++ grammar:

```js
"comments": {
    "patterns": [
        {
            "captures": {
                "0": {
                    "name": "punctuation.definition.comment.java"
                }
            },
            "match": "/\\*\\*/",
            "name": "comment.block.empty.java"
        },
```

Basically, the language defines multiple tokens under `comment`, as needed, and since the theme says that `comment.*` will be green, they all get colorized the same.

Comment: And if anyone knows how to apply custom colours to custom scopes insde a VSCode extension (maybe via CSS?), I'm all ears.

Comment: As stated in the question this is exactly the problem. You cannot just override and append own styles to a theme but you either have to live with the ones that are already defined (which might or might not fit) or you create your completely own theme (what I did), but that is not user friendly (what if they don't like your theme?). We need a way to amend any active theme from an extension, if needed.

Comment: A solution might be closer thant we think: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/17933

Although this is still open, and it sounds like what both of us want:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/11556

Comment: How to people develop these definitions? I can’t find *any* tooling, such as unit tests, or a live preview mode, which are par for the course for virtually all other syntax highlighting engines. Without this, I really don’t understand how to edit these files.

Answer (score 18):

There is no need to patch the theme, from the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes):

> To tune the editor's syntax highlighting colors, use editor.tokenColorCustomizations in your user settings settings.json file

Besides simple token customization you can fully override the TextMate rules with a slightly more complex setting, for example:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "textMateRules": [
    {
        "scope": "keyword.control.ref.latex",
        "settings": {
            "foreground": "#FF0000"
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to change PHP syntax highlighting colors, e.g. I have this `<a href="<?php echo ROOT_URL ?>">Home</a></li>` and both `echo` and the `ROOT_URL` constant are almost white color. Can you kindly hint how to change them? Or should I open a new stackoverflow question? Thank you

Answer (score 8):

**Syntax highlighting** rules are stored in `.plist` files (or alternatively in `.tmLanguage` files). In those files different token types are declared for syntax highlighting:

- What is a keyword?
- What is a string literal?
- What is a comment?
- etc.

Take a look here to get more information about it: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/colorizer

**You do not define colors in `.plist` files!**

The relation between token types and colors is done in color theme declarations.

Learn more about it here
https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/themes and here [How to add theme in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011737/how-to-add-theme-in-visual-studio-code/32335011#32335011)

In general this document is also helpful when you try to extend VSCode: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/overview

Comment: Note that you may encounter `.tmLanguage` files instead of `.plist` files, which are an XML-based alternative syntax.  Functionally, they achieve the same goal.  You only need to use one file format or the other.

Comment: Thanks, but I have already read all those documents. However, nothing explains how you would change colors. There are a few words how to import themes, download from marketplace and whatnot, but nowhere is explained how to customize a theme or even create one from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider using a [color theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes)

Since [VSCode 1.44 (March 2020)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/b4a561a6247193931c0c1b9da743cad5b282e5ca/release-notes/v1_44.md#theme-support-for-semantic-tokens), you now have:

> ### Theme Support for Semantic Tokens
>
> Color themes can now write rules to color semantic tokens reported by language extensions like TypeScript.
>
> ```
> "semanticHighlighting": true,
> "semanticTokenColors": {
>    "variable.declaration.readonly:java": { "foreground": "#00ff00" "fontStyle": "bold" }
> }
> ```
>
> The rule above defines that all declarations of readonly variables in Java should be colored green and bold
>
> See the [Semantic Highlighting Wiki Page](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Semantic-Highlighting-Overview) for more information.