# VSCode: is it possible to easily format/color my own "language"?

Tags: visual-studio-code, format, text-coloring

I'm using VSCode on a linux machine, but I used to use Notepad++. with windows, and within Notepad's language options (to color and format the code as java, php, c#, etç), there was an option to create your own custom formatter, and I used this option to create my own "Diary language", example:

- If I start and end a line with `*`, it formats the line with black and
  bold.
- If I start and end a line with `#`, it formats the line with red
  and plain.
- If I start a line with `>` and end it with `<`, it formats the line with blue and underline.

I know that I can develop my own plugin for vscode, but that is not easy and definitely not fast, is there an option or plugin that allows me to do this?

Yes, I can use some software or app to remind me some stuff, and I am using some, but it would be nice to have my annotations colored inside my text editor.

It's not a duplicate of [Customizing syntax highlighting in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38148857/customizing-syntax-highlighting-in-visual-studio-code) since I'm not creating my own language. This is the point of my question, I do not want to create a whole new language pack/theme, I just want some coloring, like the notepad++ option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customizing syntax highlighting in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38148857/customizing-syntax-highlighting-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second question on the page https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_common-questions seems to answer this

> Q: What if I don't want to create a full language service, can I reuse
>   existing TextMate bundles?
>
> A: Yes, you can also add support for your favorite language through
>   TextMate colorizers. See [Themes, Snippets, and Colorizers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/themes-snippets-colorizers) topic in the
>   Extension Authoring section to learn how to integrate TextMate
>   .tmLanguage syntax files into VS Code.

Which points to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/themes-snippets-colorizers, which shows you how to more easily intergrate custom colour and theme rules.

Comment: Thanks for the info and links, I've looked into them now and must say it's not that easy like notepad++, but I guess it is the only option for what I want to do, I'll try it.