# VS Code : how to use a semantic token in color theme?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

I try to update a color theme I made (simple focus) for VS Code, but I never found any guide for theme creators on how to use the new semantic tokens...

I have set `"semanticHighlighting" : true` in my theme

For example I want to color classes, and there are specific textMate scopes for class definition (`entity.name.type.class.js`) and creation (`entity.name.type.js`), but when using a class otherwise – like `MyClass.props = {}` – the only scope is a generic `variable.other.object.js` which I don't want to touch for it messes others things. So when I inspect scopes, I see the semantic token `class` that also match all classes definitions and creation, but how are we suppose to use this?

I tried naively to just add a scope "class", which isn't working.

All I can find about semantic tokens is related to creating a custom language, nothing for theme creators, so my guess was that it was just suppose to work like textMate scopes, and yet it doesn't. Please someone enlighten me!

[inspecting scopes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elpzX.png)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50994340/vs-code-how-to-set-semantic-syntax-coloring-like-eclipse-does-default-syntax-c/61464234#61464234 and others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your theme file, you need to add the `semanticTokenColors`, these as far as I have seen will override the colors you have set in `tokenColors`. The syntax is similar to `tokenColors` but you can also specify modifiers for each token like `class.defaultLibrary` or `class.declaration` you can also set all modifiers at once by setting `*.declaration`

Here is a sample

[image: Sample]

```
   "semanticTokenColors": {
      "namespace": "#ffffff",
      "type": "#ffffff",
      "struct": "#ffffff",
      "class": "#ffffff",
      "class.readonly": {
         "foreground": "#ffffff",
         "fontStyle": "bold italic"
      },
      "*.declaration" : {
         "fontStyle": "bold"
      },
      "*.readonly" : "#ffffff",
  }
```

You can find all the scopes and modifiers [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide)

> Standard semantic token types:

```
namespace
type, class, enum, interface, struct, typeParameter
parameter, variable, property, enumMember, event
function, member, macro
label
comment, string, keyword, number, regexp, operator
```

> Standard semantic token modifiers:

```
declaration
readonly, static, deprecated, abstract
async, modification, documentation, defaultLibrary
```