# Background color customization for Strings in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

Is it possible to have background color changed in visual studio code but only for few programmatic tokens like classes and strings in Java and Python.

I'm able to change color but not background color for a particular theme.

```
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[Monokai Dimmed]": {
            "enabled": true,
            "rules": {
                "module": "#943535",
                "class": {"foreground": "#943535", "bold": true}
            }
            
        }
    },
```

Comment: I have seen this feature in sublime for sure. Not sure if it's applicable to VSCode

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is more like a function of highlight? This way you can install some extensions of that type.

Besides, during your code, I still remember some settings in official document.
In the part of **Editor syntax highlighting**, there are something like:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations"
```

It can tune the editor's syntax highlighting colors('comments', 'strings', ...).
But I'm not sure this is what you want. You can see this for more information. Hope helpful.
[enter link description here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes)

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't solve for what I'm looking for

Comment: That's a pity I didn't get your meaning. But now I search and found it has no background in the official docs. Here is an article that explains **editor.tokenColorCustomizationsExperimental**: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50994340/vs-code-how-to-set-semantic-syntax-coloring-like-eclipse-does-default-syntax-c)