# VS Code textMateRules doesn't change the modifier I want

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

In the following image:

[image]

the non italic `name`, I can change its colours no problem, forget about it.
The two italic `name` are of scopes `variable.parameter`. The one in the parenthesis is can have a modifier called `declaration` that can be applied to specifically target it.

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": ["variable.parameter"], // changes both 'name's
        "settings": {
          "fontStyle": "",
          "foreground": "#DDD7C8"
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": ["variable.declaration"], // supposed to change upper one (even tried variable.parameter.declaration and it didn't work)
        "settings": {
          "fontStyle": "italic",
          "foreground": "#D58B39"
        },
      },
}
```

But the modifier doesn't get applied. Can you help me solve this please? I didn't find an answer in the documentation.

Comment: what is the exact (all) TextMateScopes for the declaration `name`, whcih language is this, looks Python, what you are using are the semantic scopes, don't know if they use the textmate color rules, where have you read how to use the modifier

Comment: `editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations`

Comment: It is Python yes. Well it's weird because all the other things I can change them, but not the modifiers.

For the declaration `name`, the exact scope is: `parameter`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61464234/9938317

Comment: https://medium.com/@danromans/how-to-customize-semantic-token-colorization-with-visual-studio-code-ac3eab96141b

Comment: you can try `"scope": ["declaration variable.parameter"]` or `"scope": ["variable.parameter declaration"]`, the scopes work like CSS

Comment: Can you answer the topic please and not in comments please? I really would like to give you credits !

Answer (score 2):

[@rioV8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9938317/riov8) gave the correct answer !

I should use `.semanticTokenColorCustomizations` instead of `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` !

Source: [Medium guide](https://medium.com/@danromans/how-to-customize-semantic-token-colorization-with-visual-studio-code-ac3eab96141b). (also suggested by [@rioV8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9938317/riov8))

Thank you for your answer [@rioV8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9938317/riov8) !