# Visual Studio custom syntax highlighting in code editor (for markdown and Hugo)

Tags: visual-studio, markdown, syntax-highlighting, hugo, hugo-shortcode

I am editing markdown files in Visual Studio. The markdown files are to be consumed by Hugo (gohugo.io) which uses specific shortcode syntax. An example is as follows;

```
{{hyperlink}}
www.whatever.com
{{/hyperlink}}
```

I am looking to change both {{hyperlink}} and {{/hyperlink}} into a different text colour.

Is there a way visual studio can do that? If so, how?

Thank you kindly
John

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38148857/customizing-syntax-highlighting-in-visual-studio-code) post.

Comment: Thank you i@itsmysterybox ... that post is about visual studio code ...(wish they named it something else, it causes endless troubles with google searches)