# Text color in vs code

Tags: colors, visual-studio-code

How do i change the color of loops(while, for, do while)  selections,(if, switch) and the color of sql code(SELECT, FROM, etc.) in visual studio code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customizing syntax highlighting in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38148857/customizing-syntax-highlighting-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: [Transact-SQL in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/tsql) -  hile typing T-SQL code, you get rich T-SQL language features like T-SQL IntelliSense (code completion), **syntax highlighting**, linting, code navigation and code snippets.

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly.