# how do I apply a custom color theme to visual studio code without publishing it

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have the .json file for my custom VS CODE theme and all the necessary components but i just dont want to publish it to the marketplace and all that. Is there a way to apply my theme without publishing it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011737/how-to-add-theme-in-visual-studio-code

Answer (score 5):

Use `vsce package` in the folder that contains `project.json` to generate a package.

Then you can then install .vsix on any machine you like

```sh
code --install-extension myextension.vsix
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_install-from-a-vsix